# how does one associate with an access point and further what is "association" with APs?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, connection, wireless-access-point

Lets say I am not associated with a router/AP. How do I "associate" myself with that router/AP? Further, what does it mean to be "associated" with that router or AP? Examples in the command line would be nice as well.

Answer (score 2):

WiFi Association basically means that you have authenticated with the AP, and are now 'linked' to it, so that the AP knows to act as the network bridge for your device, so traffic can be routed to and from your device.

Without the association part, the network would have no idea how to get packets to you.

From [Cisco](https://documentation.meraki.com/MR/WiFi_Basics_and_Best_Practices/802.11_Association_process_explained):

> The three 802.11 connection states are...
>
> 1. Not authenticated or associated.
> 2. Authenticated but not yet associated.
> 3. Authenticated and associated.
>
> A mobile station must be in an authenticated and associated state
>   before bridging will occur.
>
> The mobile station and AP will exchange a series of 802.11 management
>   frames in order to get to an authenticated and associated state.

From [vocal.com](http://www.vocal.com/networking/802-11-authentication-and-association/):

> **Association**
>
> Once a node has been authenticated it must become associated with an
>   AP. This is how the network determines where to send data that is
>   intended for that node. It routes it through the AP that the node is
>   associated with. This is why a node may only be associated with a
>   single AP. There is also a disassociation procedure where by the node
>   can disconnect from the WLAN. This prevents the AP from continuing to
>   attempt to transmit data to this node after it has left the WLAN.